# Реализация своего AutoMapper. C#

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Я использую в своем учебном проекте AutoMapper, но мне он кажется неудобным инструментом. Я сделал свою функцию для конвертации данных из ViewModel в Model и обратно. Переносятся только свойства.

```
public static class Mapper
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>> _propertiesDictionaries
        = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>>();

    public static T Map<T>(object obj) where T : new()
    {
        var objProperties = GetProperties(obj.GetType());
        var resultPropertyes = GetProperties(typeof(T));
        var result = new T();
        foreach (var resultProperty in resultPropertyes)
        {
            if (objProperties.TryGetValue(resultProperty.Key, out var objProperty))
            {
                resultProperty.Value.SetValue(result, objProperty.GetValue(obj));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> GetProperties(Type objType)
    {
        if (!_propertiesDictionaries.TryGetValue(objType, out var propertiesInfoDictionary))
        {
            var infos = objType.GetProperties();
            propertiesInfoDictionary = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in infos)
            {
                propertiesInfoDictionary.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo);
            }
            _propertiesDictionaries.Add(objType, propertiesInfoDictionary);
        }
        return propertiesInfoDictionary;
    }
}
```

Можно ли сделать мою функцию лучше/быстрее? Какие есть аналоги у AutoMapper?

**Update 1 Версия с использованием Expression:**

```
public static class MapperExpression
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>> _propertiesDictionaries
        = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>>();

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>> _mappersDictionaries = new
        Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>>();

    public static T Map<T>(object source) where T : new()
    {
        var targetType = typeof(T);
        var sourceType = source.GetType();
        if (_mappersDictionaries.TryGetValue(targetType, out var targetTypeMappers))
        {
            if (targetTypeMappers.TryGetValue(sourceType, out var mapper))
            {
                return (T)mapper.Invoke(source);
            }
            else
            {
                mapper = CreateMapper<T>(source.GetType());
                targetTypeMappers.Add(sourceType, mapper);
                return (T)mapper.Invoke(source);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            targetTypeMappers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();
            var mapper = CreateMapper<T>(source.GetType());
            targetTypeMappers.Add(source.GetType(), mapper);
            _mappersDictionaries.Add(targetType, targetTypeMappers);
            return (T)mapper.Invoke(source);
        }
    }

    private static Func<object, object> CreateMapper<T>(Type sourceType) where T : new()
    {
        var sourceProperties = GetProperties(sourceType);
        var targetPropertyes = GetProperties(typeof(T));

        var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        var sourceExpr = Expression.Convert(paramExpr, sourceType);

        var bindings = new List<MemberBinding>();

        foreach (var targetProperty in targetPropertyes)
        {
            if (sourceProperties.TryGetValue(targetProperty.Key, out var sourceProperty))
            {
                bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(targetProperty.Value, Expression.Property(sourceExpr, sourceProperty)));
            }
        }
        var resultExpr = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(T)), bindings);
        var mapperExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(resultExpr, paramExpr);
        return mapperExpr.Compile();
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> GetProperties(Type objType)
    {
        if (!_propertiesDictionaries.TryGetValue(objType, out var propertiesInfoDictionary))
        {
            var infos = objType.GetProperties();
            propertiesInfoDictionary = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in infos)
            {
                propertiesInfoDictionary.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo);
            }
            _propertiesDictionaries.Add(objType, propertiesInfoDictionary);
        }
        return propertiesInfoDictionary;
    }
}
```

Сравнение первой версии со второй (.net core 2.0, 2000000 конвертаций):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно. Вместо прямой работы со свойствами составьте выражение:

```
 var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
 var sourceExpr = Expression.Convert(paramExpr, obj.GetType());

 var bindings = new List<MemberBinding>();
 foreach (var resultProperty in resultPropertyes) {
     if (ваша логика) {
         bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(resultProperty, источник));
     }
 }
 var resultExpr = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(T)), bindings);
 var mapperExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<object,T>>(resultExpr, paramExpr);
 var mapper = mapperExpr.Compile();
 return mapper(obj);
```

В приведенном мной виду работать будет медленнее чем через рефлексию. Но если закешировать делегат `mapper` для пары ключей `typeof(T), obj.GetType()` наподобие того как вы сделали со списком свойств - выполняться он будет намного быстрее чем через рефлексию.

Comment: честно говоря мне сложно понять что происходит в вашем коде, можете прокомментировать строки?

Comment: @mirypoko составляется `LambdaExpression`, компилируется в делегат и исполняется

Comment: я не могу понять как использовать ваш код. У меня возникает исключение на строчке `bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(targetProperty.Value, sourceExpr));` Argument types do not match

Comment: @mirypoko а куда вы дели поиск свойства-источника и доступ до него? `sourceExpr` - это же объект-источник целиком, вы не можете положить его в свойство `resultProperty`.

Comment: @mirypoko я же не просто так написал в коде `источник` - предполагалось что эту часть напишите вы сами.

Comment: Я не очень умный, мне нужно расписывать по шагам. Вот как я понимаю ваш код: 1) Создается параметр типа object 2) Создается операция преобразования параметра к типу аргумента функции 3) Что делает List<MemberBinding> я не понял 4) В цикле к листу добавляется операции инициализации поля. Чем является источник я не понял :( Под логикой я понимаю проверку существования у типа аргумента копируемого поля 5) Создается объект целевого типа, у него устанавливаются свойства, заданные в цикле 6) Создается лямбда 7) Компилируется делегат 8) Возвращается результат вызова делегата

Comment: @mirypoko смотрите, вам надо скопировать значение из одного свойства в другое. Первое называется свойством-источником, второе - свойством-приемником. Вам надо выразить первое в виде [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Вы так имели в виду? `bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(targetProperty.Value, Expression.Property(sourceExpr, sourceProperty)));`

Comment: @mirypoko да, например так

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Вроде все работает. Только скорость не сильно отличается. Может я сделал что-то не так?

Comment: @mirypoko возможно, вы неправильно меряете скорость...

Comment: @mirypoko или же вы забыли закешировать mapper

Comment: я собираю все делегаты в словари и использую их, когда появляется функция с такой же комбинацией типов источника и результата

Comment: @mirypoko  ох, а DynamicInvoke-то зачем? Можно же было использовать `Func<object, object>` вместо `Func<object,T>` если у вас не получилось закешировать делегаты второго типа...

Comment: Исправил, получилось в 10 раз быстрее!